# Mobile payment integration for my Android e-hailing app

Tags: android, mobile, paypal, stripe-payments, braintree

My startup is developing a real-time marketplace platform for taxi companies somewhat similar to Hailo, Get taxi, Uber and Lyft (more or less), etc.

We are shopping around for a mobile payment solution and so far, we looked at the products offered by PayPal, Intuit, Braintree, and Stripe.
We are having a hard time with finding the mobile payment solution that fits our requirements.

Requirements:

1) (Must have) Passenger should be able to pay within the app by using previously added payment methods such as Credit Cards (CCs), Paypal (optional). Passenger is asked to enter the CC information only once when they sign up (or add a new card), so the CC info needs to be stored somewhere and retrieved when needed seamlessly. However, we would really prefer not to apply for PCI compliance.

Q.1) Let’s say I use PayPal Mobile SDK 2.* for payment system in our app. In the above scenario (1), is the passenger required to have a PayPal account (even for just using CCs for payment) and link it to our app?

Note: I have spent a lot of time digging into PayPal Mobile SDK 2.0 documentation (also called their support). I was told by the support person that merchants cannot store credit card info with PayPal for mobile payments (which I thought was the whole point of SDK 2.0).

2) (Optional) Passenger should be able to pay with a physical credit card by swiping it in the reader plugged into the driver’s smartphone. However, we need to integrate this process into our app (which is not currently supported by PayPal Here and Square). So, basically we need an API provider that allows creating custom POS integrated with our app.

Q. 2) Am I right when saying that scenario (2) cannot be accomplished with PayPal, Braintree, Intuit, or Stripe?

Q.3) Do you have any suggestions regarding the payment system that would allow us to implement scenarios (1) and (2)? just scenario (1)?

Please help if you have dealt with similar problems or know more about the subject.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Q3. You can also check out LevelUp. Facilitates [in-app payments](http://developer.thelevelup.com/online-ordering/) similar to PayPal and Stripe.

Similar to PayPal, it will allow you to store an access token after the user links their account. You will not be able to charge the card directly, as this would subject you to PCI compliance. LevelUp does not support the ability to swipe a physical credit card.

Answer (score 0):

A. to Q. 1) Yes, the passenger is required to have a PayPal account if you want to enable future payments.  PayPal stores and charges the credit card, without the merchant having access to it.  This is pretty much the core of the Digital Wallet industry.  You might have thought that you could process the credit card yourself, after retrieving it from PayPal. This is not supported, and would subject you to PCI compliance-ness.

A. to Q. 2) PayPal Here does not have a [publicly available SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/1) yet.

A. to Q. 3) Just scenario 1 can easily be accomplished by integrating the 2.0 PayPal SDK.

Comment: We decided to limit our payments to paypal only for the first release.  To make things even easier, we were thinking of offloading user account management to PayPal as well, using Log in with PayPal integration. Is it possible in Mobile SDK 2.0 ? Would you recommend doing that?
Thanks!

Comment: In its current form, no, Log in with PayPal is only supported in the [browser](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/), and not accessible via the sdk.  Look forward to this being added in the future!